# Adding a apprequest from user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests, koala

I am trying to add an app request from a user using Koala/Omniauth

```
@graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(current_user.omnitoken)
@graph.put_object("me", "apprequests", {:appid => MY_APP_ID, :to => USER_ID,  :message => "Come join me!"} )
```

I dont get any errors, but the request does not reach the user. Is the code correct/am i missing something?

Edit: The users I am inviting have not (yet) accepted the app, however the user that IS inviting have, is this possible to do or does it require a user-popup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users can use the dialog to send user-user requests to their friends who are not app users (edit: or to app users who are not their friends)

Apps can use the API directly to send app-user requests to existing users only, not to non-users

Comment: What's the point of sending a request to someone who is already a user?

Comment: Why would apps be able to send requests to arbitrary users they have no relationship with? it'd be rife with spam almost immediately. App->User requests are a reengagement channel to inform users that something has changed in the app and they should come back, e.g. tournament has ended, building complete, new feature unlocked, etc

Comment: I have been researching this all day and it seems correct. It's unfortunate that you can't programmatically create user to user app requests.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application is not in sandbox mode or that the people you are sending invites to have the correct permissions to access your sandboxed application. ( that means administrators/developers/testers )

Comment: it is not in sandbox mode, and it works to invite users if I use the javascript-popup from facebook...

Comment: In that case you'll have to wait for someone to provide more insight who knows more about the SDK you are using.  This **is** possible with the PHP SDK...